# merge two array with loop and key name

Tags: php, arrays

i have two separate arrays `$first_one:`

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_date] => 2019-10-16
            [_number] => 1
            [_order] => 1
            [name] => jack
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1253
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_date] => 2020-10-11
            [_number] => 2
            [_order] => 2
            [name] => joey
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1433
                )

        )

)
```

and the `$second_array:`

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-10-16
            [number] => 1
            [order] => 1
            [name] => jack
            [last_name] => foobar
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1253
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-10-11
            [number] => 2
            [order] => 2
            [name] => joey
            [last_name] => foobar
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1433
                )

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-10-28
            [number] => 3
            [order] => 3
            [name] => tom
            [last_name] => foobar
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1593
                )

        )

)
```

they are very similar but they came from different api's and they are different in numbers and also some key names.

so what i'm trying to do is to count the `$first_one` arrays and if for that many loop through the `$second_one` (in this example is 2)  and  if the `[_number]` `[_order]` from $first_one was equal (==) to `[number]` `[number]` $second_one then take some info (for example the last name) from it and put in a new array.

so is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Show your attempt to solve your task, we wiil __not__ write code for you.

Comment: Do you mean `if the [_number] [_order] from $first_one was equal (==) to [number] [order] $second_one` I think you probably do

Comment: @u_mulder i'm sorry i usuallypost my attempt but in this i don't know how to start

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes that what i mean

Comment: Surely, you can make some sort of attempt

Comment: " i'm sorry i usuallypost my attempt but in this i don't know how to start" - I don't "buy" that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr1 = [ [ '_date' => '2019-10-16','_number' => 1,'_order' => 1,
            'name' => 'jack','other_ids' => ['b_id' => 1253]
          ],
          ['_date' => 2020-10-11,'_number' => 2,'_order' => 2,
                'name' => 'joey','other_ids' => ['b_id' => 1433]
          ]
];

$arr2 = [ [ 'date' => '2019-10-16','number' => '1','order' => '1',
        'name' => 'jack','last_name' => 'foobar','other_ids' => ['b_id' => 1253]
          ],
          [ 'date' => '2019-10-11','number' => '2','order' => '2',
        'name' => 'joey','last_name' => 'foobar','other_ids' => ['b_id' => 1433]
         ],
         [ 'date' => '2019-10-28', 'number' => '3', 'order' => '3',
        'name' => 'tom', 'last_name' => 'foobar', 'other_ids' => ['b_id' => 1593]
         ],
];

// first make second array more directly searchable
// make new array with the `number` as the key
foreach( $arr2 as $a){
    $arr2new[$a['number']] = $a;
}

foreach ($arr1 as $a) {
    if ( array_key_exists($a['_number'], $arr2new) && 
        $a['_order'] == $arr2new[$a['_order']]['order'] )  
    {
        $merged[] = ['name'=>$a['name'], 'other_ids' => $a['other_ids']];
    }
}
print_r($merged);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [name] => jack
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1253
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [name] => joey
            [other_ids] => Array
                (
                    [b_id] => 1433
                )
        )
)
```