# Compare and Update PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP:

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => t35wmkbg
            [task] => Zaphod
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => cwg2yc5q
            [task] => Arthur
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
             [autoid] => 85q4bcmy
             [task] => Ford
             [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
             [autoid] => yc5qcwg2
             [task] => Trillian
             [progress] => incomplete
        )
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => t35wmkbg
            [task] => Zaphod
            [progress] => complete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => 85q4bcmy
            [task] => Ford
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => cwg2yc5q
            [task] => Arthur
            [progress] => pending
        )

)
```

I need to:

- Step through **Array 1**, and check if the autoid exists in **Array 2**.
- If it does exist, update the `progress` field to match.

So the ideal output when using the arrays above would be:

**Array 3**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => t35wmkbg
            [task] => Zaphod
            [progress] => complete
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => cwg2yc5q
            [task] => Arthur
            [progress] => pending
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
             [autoid] => 85q4bcmy
             [task] => Ford
             [progress] => incomplete
        )
 
    [3] => Array
        (
             [autoid] => yc5qcwg2
             [task] => Trillian
             [progress] => incomplete
        )

)
```

I am not sure how best to go about this, if anyone has any thoughts or pointers that would be awesome.

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward task involving a loop and some `if` conditions. Give it a shot and if you have specific issues with your code, edit them into the question.

Comment: [This answer does something very similiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751417/2310830)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the arr2 so its index is the `autoid` then you can use it easily to get the progress value.
Then just foreach over arr1 and apply changes to `progress` if they exist

```
$arr1 = [
            ['autoid' => 't35wmkbg','task' => 'Zaphod','progress' => 'incomplete'],
            ['autoid' => 'cwg2yc5q', 'task' => 'Arthur', 'progress' => 'incomplete'],
            ['autoid' => '85q4bcmy', 'task' => 'Ford', 'progress' => 'incomplete'],
            ['autoid' => 'yc5qcwg2', 'task' => 'Trillian', 'progress' => 'incomplete']
        ];

$arr2 = [
            ['autoid' => 't35wmkbg', 'task' => 'Zaphod', 'progress' => 'complete'],
            ['autoid' => '85q4bcmy', 'task' => 'Ford', 'progress' => 'incomplete'],
            ['autoid' => 'cwg2yc5q', 'task' => 'Arthur', 'progress' => 'pending']
        ];

#first make arr2 indexable on the autoid
foreach ($arr2 as $a) {
    $arr2search[$a['autoid']] = $a;
}

foreach ($arr1 as $a){
    // do we have an autoid in arr2
    if ( isset($arr2search[$a['autoid']])){
        $a['progress'] = $arr2search[$a['autoid']]['progress'];
    }
    $merged[] = $a;
    
}

print_r($merged);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        ([autoid] => t35wmkbg,  [task] => Zaphod,  [progress] => complete)

    [1] => Array
        ([autoid] => cwg2yc5q, [task] => Arthur, [progress] => pending )

    [2] => Array
        ([autoid] => 85q4bcmy,  [task] => Ford,  [progress] => incomplete )

    [3] => Array
        ([autoid] => yc5qcwg2, [task] => Trillian, [progress] => incomplete )
)
```